# Is the space $s$ separable?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

There is a question "Prove the space $s$ is not separable".And let $x=(x_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$, the space $s$ is a sequence space s.t. $s=\{x\}$ with $\|x\|_{s}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{i}}\frac{|x_{i}|}{1+|x_{i}|}$.

But,I think that the set consisting of all finitely nonzero sequences with rational components is countable and dense in $s$,so the space $s$ is separable.Am I wrong?

Comment: How is this a norm?

Comment: What is $s$? The space of *all* real or complex sequences or the space of rapidly decreasing sequences? I've seen $\mathrm s$ used for the latter in e.g. [Meise & Vogt](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Functional-Analysis-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0198514859).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’ve written as a norm isn’t one: it’s not true, for instance, that $\|2x\|_s=2\|x\|_s$. However, if you set

$$d(x,y)=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{|x_k-y_k|}{2^k\left(1+|x_k-y_k|\right)}\;,$$

the function $d$ is a metric on the space of real sequences. And yes, the set of rational sequences with only finitely many non-zero terms is indeed a countable dense subset of the resulting metric space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I'm sorry that I mistook it.You're right,the metric is what you've written in this question.So,as you said,I'm right,aren't I?And can I think this question is a 'fault'?

Comment: @user98663: Yes, the set that you described is dense in that metric and countable. I’m not sure what you mean by a ‘fault’.

Comment: @BrianMScott: Sorry.I mean,the space is separable,but the question is to prove it is not separable,so the question is ... wrong.(?)(I can't find a good word to describe it.)

Comment: @user98663: Ah, okay, now I understand: yes, if the question asked you to prove that the space was not separable, it’s wrong. (You could describe it as a *faulty question*.)